# My acer laptop wont start after I rebooted Ubuntu

Tags: boot

My computer wont start because of a network syncronization error and a network name resolution error. It was saying that it was failing when i clicked f5. I don't want to lose my computer so how can i fix this?

EDIT: I'm using a dual boot for windows and ubuntu... and I'm stuck on the booting screen and the errors keep looping and looping, how do I get out of this booting screen. I'm very new to Linux I got it like 2 days ago so I'm not the best at understanding what you are saying.

Comment: There is no information to have an idea why this happened. But you can always boot with a LiveUSB and save your data.

Comment: Im using a dual boot for windows and ubuntu... and im stuck on the booting screen and the errors keep looping and looping, how do i get out of this booting screen. I'm very new to linux i got it like 2 days ago so im not the best at understanding what you are saying

Comment: I suggest booting from a LiveUSB, saving your data and reinstalling the system. It is feasible for a newbie.

Comment: Yes, exactly how do i do this? And i boot from a usb. And i really dont care about my data on linux i have almost none

Answer (score 0):

You can use repair boot, it has an option call : "boot reinstall" and it use a graphical interface or you can use command line using grub wiki

Comment: How? and i clicked ubuntu on the grub menu and now its not booting and idk how to get back to the grub menu

Answer (score 0):

The following is the answer for this issue.

I tried using the "Boot-Repair-Disk" thumb drive again, and instead used the steps described in the Grub fix Grub not working after Windows 8.1 update on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS . So in boot repair select ADVANCE OPTIONS. It presented a new set of instructions I didn't see the last time I tried. It gave me selections to re-install Grub in the /sda, and NOT install the EFI in a separate partition, like it was doing. I think that selection UNCHECKED allowed the EFI to be installed in /sda, along with Grub. Upon BOOTing I see the Grub menu, BUT with ONLY Ubuntu & Options as selections. There doesn't seem to be a Windows selection in the Grub.

On my machine you press F12 during Boot to bring up the hard drive menu, select which one to boot from. BUT, if the Windows drive is selected, it first showed the "Starting Windows" screen for a few seconds, then defaulted to the Grub menu, then to Ubuntu.

Since monkeying around with this issue, other errors cropped up with Apt, dbus, etc (search my past posts to see what I mean), which necessitated me having to backup all data, then wipe the drive clean, and do a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS to correct all these issues. Currently, I have to use rEFInd Boot Manager http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html on a disc to boot into Xubuntu, which shows a Grub menu that does show Ubuntu, Options, and a Windows boot loader - seemingly solving this issue. After boot, I can remove the disc and replace it with anything, and Xubuntu works great.

So, Back in this Saddle again.

Comment: I actually dont know how this works and how to do this once again, im a newbue